# Why Dagger doesn't generate Dagger Component?

Tags: dagger

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkKiu.png) [My dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj0Ew.png) [plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gysx.png) [Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Om6.png) [Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73u43.png)

Answer (score 0):

Everthing is looking good, but you have to create DaggerAppComponent by building project using gradle build and then use it get dependencies.

```
AppComponent mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .netModule(new NetModule("https://api.github.com"))
            .build();
```